# Cannot create class-file Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar API into my android project and I follow the tutorial here

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

At step 5 create a new java class

I right click project folder src>main>java>com>example>utarapp and then new>file and entered the file name but then it has this error

[image]

What's going on ?

I'm using android studio 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create file with same name which is already present in the same package. This may be one possible reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are right-clicking on the upper level in your application's directory tree.

Right click on one of the **files** inside the `utarapp` folder and then select `Java class` option from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was happenning because of the **length of the class name**. In my case it was "ChallengesFragmentPagerAdapter"!

Changing it to "ChallengesPagerAdapter" solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Create a blank Activity then remove "extends Activity" from the activity class.